# Debugging existing executable doesn't allow to set breakpoints in library files

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I have seen that eclipse provides a feature to load an existing executable in order to debug it, so I was following the guidelines described in here to do so. I have to say that I didn't compile the binary in eclipse, I was using my own makes files though.

However, although I can import my binary I cannot set breakpoints into the libraries( shared or not) which the binary has, as is stated in the last point of the guideline, and I don't know exactly the reason. Instead of having the content of the library, I get nothing, even if I click on the associated plus icon to the lib, see figures below

[image: blank libraries content]
[image: loaded executable]

At the beginning I thought it was due to the fact that my binary didn't have the debugging flags enabled, but i checked the binary with the commands below, getting an expected output, which means that debugging flags are enables, aren't they?

```
readelf --debug-dump=decodedline AudioControlApp

objdump --debugging AudioControlApp
```

Then, I was wondering, why cannot I set the breakpoints on those libraries? Does my binary miss some compilation option?

thanks in advance,

Regards